# IntelliJのリモートデバッグポートは開けっ放しでも安全？

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJのリモートデバッグではデフォルトで`5005`ポートを使用します。
リモートデバッグ可能なコマンドでJarを実行し、IntelliJからこのポートにアクセスするとブレークポイントなどのデバッグが可能になります。
このデバッグポートですが常にIP無制限で開けておいても安全でしょうか？

ソースコードと実行Jarは非公開になっています。

追記
疑問に思っているのは
デバッグ実行してポートを開けていてもソースコードやJarプログラムがなければデバッグ操作できないのかな？と思っていまして。
そこら変どうなのでしょう...
考えてみるとたとえソースコードがなくてもデバッグ操作できそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

万全を期すなら必要時以外は閉じておいた方が無難だと思いますが、ネットワークのセキュリティを考えるときにはスコープ (範囲) を意識してみてください。

- リモートデバッグが LAN の内側で完結しているなら、外部からのアクセスは恐らくルータやファイアウォール等で守られていると思うので、そこまで神経質になる必要は無いかもしれません。
- 一方、インターネット経由でアクセスするために外部にもポートを開けている状態であれば、セキュリティも慎重に考慮する必要があります。

Answer (score -1):

まあ、そのポートを使ってあなたのそのシステムを乗っ取ることができるってことになりますが、それを判断するのはあくまであなたとなります。
それで大丈夫だと判断されるのであれば、きっと大丈夫、としか赤の他人には判断できません